# How to use Entity Framework to just create a table in an existing SQL Server database?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, entity-framework

I am currently trying to create a table with EF code-first in a SQL Server where I only have permissions to create tables in an existing database.

I cannot drop the entire database. I tried using migration `update-table` to let EF create the table for me, but because a `__MigrationHistory` table already exists (and is linked to different table), this didn't work.

Does anyone have a solution for my problem?

Answer (score 3):

You need not to drop the whole database,

Add the class for the new Table, let's say your new Table is "person"

```
public class Person
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and Add following line to DbContext

```
 public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }
```

Now you need to Add this table to the existing Database. The easiest way is Go to Nuget Package Manager Console (Tools-> Nuget Package Manager -> Package Manager Console) inside visual studio

```
type Add-Migration AddedPersonTable
```

This will create a new entry in the Migration Table

```
and then type Update-Database
```

This will Add the new persons table to the existing database

Read [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj193542.aspx) for More information about Migrations.

Comment: That's what I already tried but I got the error "There is already an object named '__MigrationHistory' in the database". That's because the database is used by a different user who also uses EF. Also I cannot edit the MigrationHistory because I do not have the permissions to do so. Is there a way to just create the table without the need for the MigrationHistory Table?